# matplotlib adding blue shade to an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib for basic operations but I see that whenever I try to display an image using matplotlib, a blue shade is added to the image.

For example,

Code:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread("./data/images/cat_and_dog.jpg")
cv2.imshow('image',image) # Display the picture


plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

cv2.waitKey(0) # wait for closing
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Ok, destroy the window
```

And the images shown by opencv gui and matplotlib are different.

[image]

Even the histogram is distorted and not just the display

[image]

How do I avoid this blue shade on an image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

see: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#using-matplotlib

> Warning: Color image loaded by OpenCV is in BGR mode. But Matplotlib
>   displays in RGB mode. So color images will not be displayed correctly
>   in Matplotlib if image is read with OpenCV. Please see the exercises
>   for more details.

you can replace your `plt.imshow(image)` line with the following lines:

```
im2 = image.copy()
im2[:, :, 0] = image[:, :, 2]
im2[:, :, 2] = image[:, :, 0]
plt.imshow(im2)
```

Comment: Yes. I just noticed it too. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Complementing @ophir answer.
You can also use cv2.cvtColor to convert from BGR to RGB